# Programming a Bivariate Normal CDF in R

Tags: r, statistics

I have a question regarding coding a function that contains a bivariate normal CDF in R.  The function I am trying to code requires one bivariate normal CDF, that should be calculated differently depending on the observation.  Specifically, depending upon the value of a certain variable, the correlation should "switch" between being positive and negative, but there should be no difference in the call.

This style of function has been coded in LIMDEP and I am trying to replicate it, but have not been able to get it to work in R.  The command in LIMDEP to calculate a bivariate normal CDF is "BVN(x1, x2, r)", which explicitly requires the two variables used for calculation (x1, x2) and the correlation (r).  LIMDEP uses the Gauss-Laguerre 15 point quadrature to calculate the bivariate normal CDF.

In R, it appears that two packages calculate the multivariate normal CDF.  I have been trying the mnormt package (though there is the mvtnorm package as well--I do not see a major difference) that uses the Genz method, which seems to be similar, but more general than the Gauss-Laguerre 15 quadrature method used in LIMDEP (referencing the papers under ?pmnorm).

Everytime that I have tried to use the mnormt package, the command pmnorm(), requires the form: pmnorm(data, mean, varcov), which I have not been able to code for correlation switching.

Any ideas how to get this to work??

Here is an example of some trivial code to explain what I am talking about what I would like to do (except inside of a function without the for loop):

```
 library(mnormt)
 A <- c(0,1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1)
 q <- 2*A-1 
 set.seed(1234)
 x <- rnorm(10)
 y <- rnorm(10, 2, 2)

 #Need to return a value of the CDF for each row of data:
 cdf.results <- 0
 for(i in 1:length(A)){
 vc.mat <- matrix(c(1, q[i]*.7, q[i]*.7, 1.3), 2, 2)
 cdf.results[i] <- pmnorm(cbind(x[i], y[i]), c(0, 0), vc.mat) 
 }
 cdf.results
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: so what is it exactly that's not working for you? You say *the command pmnorm(), requires the form: pmnorm(data, mean, varcov), which I have not been able to code for correlation switching.*

Comment: Every time that I tried to code up the var/cov matrix within a likelihood function, it would not properly gather values in a manner consistent with the underlying distribution.  For example, if A=0, then the correlation should be negative, but if A=1, it should be positive and that changes based on each observation.  I think the answer helps me out and gets me much closer than where I was!

Comment: Have you transferred further calculations from LIMDEP/NLOGIT to R?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like all you need is 1) to make your script into a function so it can apply to arbitrary x,y and q  and 2) to get rid of the for loop. If that is the case `?function` and `?apply` should give you what you need.

```
BVN=function(x,y,q) {

  cdf.results=apply(cbind(x,y,q),1,FUN=function(X) 
       {
      x=X[1]
      y=X[2]
      q=X[3]
          vc.mat <- matrix(c(1, q*.7, q*.7, 1.3), 2, 2)
          pmnorm(cbind(x, y), c(0, 0), vc.mat)     
                    # I think you may want c(0,2) but not sure
        }
                   )
 cdf.results
}



BVN(x,y,q)
```

Here x,y and q are how you wrote above. Maybe you want the function to take matrix r, like in limdep? It wouldn't be much different.

Comment: Thanks so much.  I am still relatively new to R and I understand "apply" stuff for basic stuff, but did not know that they were useful within functions (in terms of being efficient coding).  I think this will provide what I need to fix the code.  

One question to make sure of:  These sorts of functions can be within other functions correct?

Comment: I am not sure that the 'apply' is much better than the 'for' version that you wrote. And yes, once you initialize the function(IE run lines 1:14) you can call it (line 18) within another function.

Comment: Well we will see how it goes.  It is running now.  The optimization routine is taking some time, so the code might not be efficient, but we that will be the next step.  First I need to make sure it works!  I'll see what the results look like off of the "known" data and parameters.  I appreciate the help.